# HyperLedger Fabric v2.3 Endorsement Policy did not come into action

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was trying to test out the endorsement policy feature of Fabric with the [Running a Fabric Application tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) and I have encountered a few questions/issues.

Instead of using LevelDB, I up the network using CouchDB by changing the command to `./network.sh up createChannel -c mychannel -ca -s couchdb`.
After the call to `InitLedger`, I manually edit **asset2**'s `"Size"` field value to another random value through fauxton, accessed from http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/ (couchdb0, which belongs to organization 1). So at this point, **asset2** has 2 different value sitting in couchdb0 and couchdb1.

Then I invoke the `UpdateAsset` function in the chaincode to update **asset2**'s value. I was expecting an error about endorsement policy is not met or something to be thrown as the different value of **asset2** in couchdb0 and couchdb1 should results in different RW set.

```
peer0.org1.example.com|2021-03-23 09:03:09.568 UTC [statecouchdb] commitUpdates -> WARN 0b4 CouchDB batch document update encountered an problem. Reason:Document update conflict., Retrying update for document ID:asset2
```

I did notice this warning in `logspout` however there was no error caught in my try catch block, and it seems that a valid block is committed and the world states is getting updated as usual without any error.

Shouldn't the different RW Set would cast the transaction as invalid and the world states wouldn't be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected. You updated the size field but not the version field. The read set check only checks the version field. It is up to the chaincode to check other fields such as asset ownership (and size, if there are business rules around that, such as size not being allowed to change in an update). The asset transfer chaincode is a trivial sample and only checks for asset existence in state database by key. So in your case chaincode execution succeeded because it passed the asset existence check, endorsements succeeded, and validation succeeded since both endorsements were over the same read set (version) and write set.

You get the CouchDB warning because the internal CouchDB revision number was different due to your external update, but this is not a fatal problem and gets resolved by a retry (CouchDB internal revision numbers are not guaranteed to be the same across state databases since peer may update the same state multiple times, e.g. in crash recovery scenarios).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! There is an extended question/finding from this experiment. After manual edit to couchdb through fauxton, I realize that getState(key) and getHistoryForKey(key) are returning results that are not tampered (quering from nodes that are the same organization with couchdb0) whereas getStateByKey("","") returns results that are tampered. Does that mean getState(key) queries from the blockchain (not world state / couchdb) and getStateByKey("","") queries from the worldstate / couchdb?